# how to write to a named pipe and don't wait for reading the pipe

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

i'm writing to a pipe until user enters the string "end". if the user enters the string "end", i suppose to go further. here I've to close the pipe and print the message "After Written to Pipe".  But its not printing the line "After Written to Pipe" even i entered "end" string. How can i close the pipe and go further even-though there is no process to read the pipe?..

Hi here is my code.,

```
int main() {
int fd;
char *b, *c;
printf("Enter Str : ");
b = malloc(50);
gets(b);

while(strcmp(b,"end")!=0){
    if(access("MSG",F_OK) != -1)    // check pipe is already available.
    {
        fd = open("MSG", O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, b, strlen(b) );
    }
    else
    {
        if( mkfifo("MSG", 0666) != -1)  // create pipe if not available.
        {
            fd = open("MSG", O_WRONLY);
            write(fd, b, strlen(b) );               
        }
    }
    printf("Enter Str : ");
    gets(b);
}   
close(fd);
printf("After Written to Pipe");

}
```

Comment: There's a chunk of (unnecessary) code repetition there. You could use `if (access("MSG", F_OK) != 0) { if (mkfifo("MSG", 0666) != 0) ... report error and stop... }` and then have one copy of `open()` and `write()`. You should consider what happens if the FIFO creation fails. You should consider what happens if the `open()` fails.  You probably consider checking the return value from `write()`. You should not call `close()` unless you successfully opened `fd` (but the close should be in the loop with the open; you're leaking file descriptors). Are you sure you want to open the FIFO in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`mkfifo(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) manual page:

> However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it. Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.

The above paragraph means that `write` will block until there is someone reading from the FIFO, which is what you see in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Named pipes are not the right tool here, since `bash` offers no way to use them in a non-blocking mode.

You *could* write a tool in a programming language that acts like `cat`, but doesn’t block. But [none of the results I found](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=1&biw=1566&bih=1066&tbs=li:1&q=bash%20non-blocking%20named%20pipe&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=) made me happy enough to recommend them to you.

Otherwise it’s either sockets (using `netcat` and `localhost`), which unfortunately are insecure since every other user on your computer could access them too…

Or some kind of normal file that acts as a buffer. But there you’d have the problem on how to delete the lines you already read so it doesn’t flood, and race conditions, and all those nightmares.

I’m sorry, but there really isn’t a good solution here. To solve this the proper way, would require patching bash and cat to add an option to allow non-blocking behavior.